# How can I export a mongo database handler in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, commonjs

I am new to Node and Mongo, I was trying to connect to a mongo database in one file and export the database handler to many other files, so that I need not to connect to the database in all files which need a connection to it. Here is how I attempted to do it

```js
// db.js
var client = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert')
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

client.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  assert.equal(err, null)
  module.exports = db
})
```

After exporting the db handler, I tried to access methods on it in another file as follows

```js
var db = require('./db')
console.log(db.collection('col'))
```

but it throws a TypeError, saying that `db.collection` is not a function. How can I access the methods on db handler in other files?

Answer (score 4):

you need to export function and it need callback1. when  the wanted parameter can't get, set the callback1 to callback2 about the async function.

db.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
let callback, db;
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  db = client.db(dbName);
  callback(db)

  client.close();
});

module.exports = function(cb){
  if(typeof db != 'undefined' ){
    cb(db)
  }else{
    callback = cb
  }
}
```

other.js

```
const mongo = require("./db");
mongo((db) => {
     //here get db handler
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best bet is to just export an init() function with a callback and then call that before you use the other db methods.  Otherwise you could try to check that its initialized at the top of each db access method but that is probably not actually a more maintainable solution since it makes it more complicated.